# Ninject bind any object of type T in request scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have an abstract class `RequestScopeContainer` which acts as a temporary data holder for the current request.

```
public abstract class RequestScopeContainer
{

}
```

Is possible to tell `Ninject` to bind any classes that implements the abstract `RequestScopeContainer` class to have the life cycle as Request Scope?

Comment: How do you register those "classes that implements the abstract RequestScopeContainer"?

Comment: You mean in `Ninject`? i was looking for something like this: `kernel.Bind<RequestScopeContainer>().InRequestScope();`, but i need to specify a class which implements the abstract `RequestScopeContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use the ninject conventions extension:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions

```
IBindingRoot.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<AbstractRequestScopeContainer>()
    .BindToSelf()
    .Configure(x => x.InRequestScope()));
```